# How to predict KNN classifier without using built-in function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I have some trouble on predicting KNN classifier without using built-in function. I got stuck here and had no idea how to go to next step. Here is my code:

```
 % calculate Euclidean distance
 dist = pdist2(test, train, 'euclidean');
 for k = [1 3 5 7]
    [~, nearest] = sort(dist, 2);
    nearst = nearest(:, 1:k);
end % for loop
```

Where `test` is a 297x64 matrix, and `train` is a 1500x64 matrix. The `dist` matrix is 297x1500. Any help will be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you managed to get sorted indices in terms of distances in your `nearst`, all you have to do is to refer to your **labels** of the original data. So you have somewhere a variable `labels` which holds a true label for each point. Use indices stored in `nearst` to read them out and simply report the most common value.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to figure out how to implement it on MATLAB.